# How to make triggers in backend with Django?

Tags: python, django, triggers, backend

I am developing a personal project where teacher accounts can design their own multiple-choice exams for student accounts.
One of the Exam class attributes is `exam_time`, an integer attribute which sets how many minutes are provided to the students when they are doing an exam.
When a student starts running an exam, the Student class has two important fields, one is `running_exam`, which sets the exam id that the student is currently doing, and the other is `exam_time`, an integer that stores how many seconds are left for that student.

```
def start_exam(request, exam_id):
    exam = Exam.objects.get(id=exam_id, students=Student.objects.get(email=request.user.email))
    if exam:
        Student.objects.filter(email=request.user.email).update(
            doing_exam=exam.id,
            exam_time=exam.time*60,
        )
        return etc...
```

Now I need a way to trigger an event for each second to update the student's `exam_time` field, subtracting -1 for each second and checking if it is not in 0.
Other way would be by doing this with JavaScript but it is maybe very vulnerable since it is pure front-end.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with jQuery.  Something like:

```
<script>
var duration = {{ exam_time }} * 100
var qTimer = duration, seconds, dispms;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    questionTimer = setInterval(function () {
        seconds = parseInt(qTimer / 100, 10);
        dispms =  parseInt(qTimer % 100, 10);
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        dispms = dispms < 10 ? "0" + dispms : dispms;

        display.textContent =  seconds+":"+dispms;

        if (--qTimer < 0) {
            clearInterval(questionTimer);
            display.textContent = "";
            qTimer = -1;
            window.location = {% url 'next-screen' %}
        }
    }, 10);
}

var display = document.querySelector('#time'); /* time is an id for a span/div where the time remaining is displayed */
startTimer(duration, display);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I am currently doing this with an ajax, but in this way if the user loses the connection, the database will stop updating user's exam time.